# Sample.split in CaTools

Tags: r

This code works for me to split the sample to create a multiple regression model.
Problem is, if I have three dependent variables (numberA, numberB, numberC) and want to do three regression models, do I have to split the sample 3 times, and change the "numberC" in the first line of code to "numberA" and "numberB" too? Like get 3 sets of training and testing data sets? Or 1 will do?

```
trainTRUEFALSEset <- sample.split(Data_after$numberC, SplitRatio = 0.66, group = NULL)
training_Set <- Data_after[trainTRUEFALSEset,]
test_Set <- Data_after[!trainTRUEFALSEset,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
split_df <- function(y, df, ratio) {
  train <- sample.split(df[[y]], SplitRatio = ratio)
  list(training_Set = df[train,], test_Set = df[!train,])  
}
lapply(c("numberA", "numberB", "numberC"), split_df, Data_after, 0.66)
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for this. I was actually wondering if I can just split the sample once, and use the training and testing set for creating 3 regression models for 3 different dependent variables, or should I split the sample differently three times? I actually don't fully understand how sample splitting works tbh although my code works.

Comment: @JordanLee If that is the case, sure you can. `sample.split` simply returns you a vector of `n` elements, each of which is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. `n` is equal to the number of rows in your dataset. When you do `Data_after[trainTRUEFALSEset,]`, you are just trying to select all rows that are marked as `TRUE` by `trainTRUEFALSEset`. In this case, all columns including your `y`s will be simultaneously trimmed down to the same size.

Comment: `Data_after[!trainTRUEFALSEset,]` just selects the reverse--those rows marked as `FALSE`. However, if there are any statistical reasons you are concerned about, maybe you should ask on 
[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or other relevant websites. But computational-wise I don't see why you can't reuse your two datasets.